# How to convert array<string> to array<struct> using Pyspark?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark `dataframe (df)` with columns - **name, id, project, start_date, status**

When used `to_json` function in aggregation, it makes the datatype of payload to be `array<string>`. How do I convert the `array<string>` to `array<struct<project:string, start_date:date, status: string>>`? This conversion is needed to access from redshift spectrum.

```
df_gp= df.groupBy(F.col('name'),
                          F.col('id')).agg(F.collect_list(
                          F.to_json(F.struct(('project'),
                                             ('start_date'),
                                             ('status')))).alias("payload"))
```

I followed steps given in,
[this documentation](https://kontext.tech/column/spark/284/pyspark-convert-json-string-column-to-array-of-object-structtype-in-data-frame)

```
import json
def parse_json(array_str):
    json_obj = json.loads(array_str)
    for item in json_obj: 
        yield (item["project"], item["start_date"],item["status"])

json_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('project', StringType(), nullable=True)
, StructField('start_date', DateType(), nullable=True)
, StructField('status', StringType(), nullable=True)]))

udf_parse_json = F.udf(lambda str: parse_json(str), json_schema)
df_new = df_gp.select(df_gp.name, df_gp.id, udf_parse_json(df_gp.payload).alias("payload"))

#works and shows intended schema
df_new.schema

# the following fails
df_new.show(truncate = False)
```

**It throws error:**

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'generator'

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need **`to_json`** in your aggregation, it works fine without it.

```
df.groupBy(F.col('name'),F.col('id')).agg(F.collect_list(
                          F.struct(('project'),
                                             ('start_date'),
                                             ('status'))).alias("payload")).printSchema()


#root
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- payload: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- project: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- start_date: date (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```